# How to jump back into a loop after jumping out of one - NASM

Tags: loops, assembly, nasm

I'm using NASM and I'm stuck on how to return back into a loop after jumping out of one.

In `_start`, I used `call loop1` to start the loop. The loop successfully runs and the first loop iteration prints out `a`, which is what I want.
The purpose of this loop is to iterate over the value in `edi` and print out each character if it is the letter `a`. Currently it only prints out one `a` if it finds at least one `a` in `edi`, and nothing if it can't find any.

Yes, all the labels used in this code are defined, so that's not the issue. Please comment if I need to post my full code.

Here is my code:

```
loop1:
    cmp  [edi], byte 0
    je   endloop

    cmp  byte [edi], 'a'
    je   istrue1

    add  edi, dword 1
    add  [n], dword 1
    jmp  loop1
endloop:
    ret

istrue1:
    mov  ecx,edi
    mov  edx,1
    call print
    jmp  loop1
```

The reason I am using this approach is because I previously did this with `.loop` inside of `_start` and it wasn't working the way I intended, so I thought there wouldn't be any issue if I put it into a procedure.

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this :)

Comment: Just for clarification, `N` is a counter. It doesn't affect anything here, and I can remove it if needed.

Comment: The `istrue1` branch never increments `edi`. It's not clear what `print` changes but if it doesn't change `edi` it should run into an endless loop instead of just printing once. If `edi` is changed then of course all bets are off.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried incrementing `edi` in `istrue1` and the same thing happens. The code for `print` is `mov  eax,4` , `mov  ebx,1` and `int  0x80`  (comment formatting on here is a little uncomfortable, sorry).

Comment: And it has a `ret` at the end, right? Otherwise that won't return and yes, that could mean only a single print :)

Comment: Haha it does now, thank you! That solved my problem, but caused another one

Comment: I now get the right amount of `a`'s being printed, but then a Segmentation Fault occurs at the end.

Comment: You maybe forgot to terminate the process.

Comment: Hmmm just after my `call loop1` line I have `call exit` and `exit` does: `mov eax,1` , `mov ebx,0` and `int 0x80`. Do I need a `ret` for this one as well or not, because it's exiting anyway?

Comment: That should be enough. Then maybe you don't even have a `0` terminator in your string so your loop goes off the end?

Comment: The current contents of the stack don't affect whether you can `call` a function and have it return or not.  No reason why calling this block from `_start` would be any different than falling into it, except of course that `endloop:` executes a `ret` which you can't do in `_start`.  Anyway, as it stands this isn't a [mcve] of anything except the infinite loop Jester pointed out, and it's not even *complete* because you don't show the definition of `print` to tell whether it clobbers any registers or not.  Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Both errors have been fixed with help from [Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/547981/jester).

The first one was fixed by adding `ret` to the end of my `print` function, and the segmentation fault was fixed by changing the first line of my `loop1` function from:

`cmp  [edi], byte 0`

To this:

`cmp  byte [edi], byte 0`

I'm not sure exactly why adding `byte` to that line fixed it, but I'm glad it worked.

Comment: NASM assembles both `cmp  byte [edi], byte 0` and `cmp  [edi], byte 0` to the same machine code ([`80 3F 00` - `cmp r/m8, imm8`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp)).  The canonical way to write that in NASM is `cmp byte [edi], 0`).  Whatever else you actually changed, that was a placebo / coincidence.